# Asp.net Resource file management from one point

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resx

I have created a class library to store application `resource.resx` files.

[image]

But my Resource files count may be increase. And Resource file contents may be grow up. In this stuation, I can not manage cotent of my resource files. I want to manage Resources from single point.

For example add a new item in Resource.resx it will automatically create in orher Resources. If I remove it will be removed in other Reource files.